# ¿Como mostar por ventana la informacion y como mostrar la ultima palabra de una frase?

Tags: javascript

si se que son dos preguntas espero que no haya mingun problema, veran quiero que se muestre la primera y ultima palabra de una frase la primera palabra de la frase soy capaz de sacarla pero no entiendo como sacar la ultima, y ademas quiero que cuando ingrese el prompt se muestre en otra ventana pero no llega a cargar la ventana:

Adjunto aqui el codigo que llevo hecho:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio2</title>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/mensaje.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Y la parte de javascript

```
var frase;
var primerapalabra;
frase = prompt('Ingrese su frase', '');
frase = primerapalabra.split(" ");
var primerapalabra = frase[0];    
        
        
    function abrir() {
        my_window = window.open("",
        "mywindow", "status=1,height=400,width=800,left=600,location=yes,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,titlebar=yes,top=300" );
            
        my_window.document.write( "<p>" + primerapalabra + "</p>");
                                      
        return my_window;
    }
            
    var unawindow = abrir()
    unawindow.document.write('<br><b>', 'Hola de nuevo', '</b><br>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores al descomponer la cadena.
Para seleccionar la primera palabra tienes que hacer el `split` sobre la cadena recuperada por el `prompt`.

Para obtener la última palabra utiliza la propiedad `.length` del array.

```js
var frase = prompt('Ingrese su frase', '');
var palabras = frase.split(" ");
var primerapalabra = palabras[0];
var ultimapalabra = palabras[palabras.length-1];
console.log(`Primera palabra: ${primerapalabra}`);
console.log(`Última palabra: ${ultimapalabra}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ultimapalabra = frase[frase.length - 1];
```